# Obtain result set from table within column range?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

How to obtain ResultSet from DB table within range ?

```
 String sql=SELECT * From Employee Where Salary<=? AND Salary>=?;

 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

 String lowest_salary=In.nextLine();

 String max_salary=In.nextLine(); 

 preparedStatement.setString(1,lowest_salary); 

 preparedStatement.setString(1,max_salary);

 ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Can I assigned values as parameter twice to DB table column(EmployeeSalary)? What's solution?

Comment: What is the result of code you have now?

Comment: How about using `setString(2,max_salary)`

Comment: I want to get ResultSet as specified range by user. What is the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Your main issue is that you are using `.setString(1, ...)` twice, which is incorrect. You have two parameter placeholders (`?`) in your SQL command text so you need to set the first parameter value with the index `1` and the second parameter value with the index `2`.

Also be sure that you `set` the parameter values using the method that matches the column type. `.setString` is to be used with text columns. A column named "Salary" is more likely to be numeric, so you should probably be using `.setInt` if the column is integer, or `.setBigDecimal` if the column is a decimal or currency type.

Comment: ok, But how I set two parameter to the same column to get ResultSet from table because salary column has index #1?

Comment: You have done that in the command text. The first parameter (index 1) refers to the placeholder in `Salary<=?` and the second parameter (index 2) refers to the placeholder in `Salary>=?`. The indexes do not refer to the column names, only to the parameter placeholders (`?`) in the order in which they appear in the command text.